# What does くるんてしてて mean？

Tags: meaning

[image]

I think してて　is していて, but I can't figure out what くるんて could mean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Removing the slang it's read as

> あ、えり足　は　くるん　と　していて　かわいい

えり足　means

> hairline at nape of neck; nape of neck​

くるん seems to be related to くるくる which means, among others

> 1. whirling; revolving; spinning; going round and roun
> 2. coiling around; winding around; rolling around​

くるん seems to mean that the hair is curled only once, instead of repeatedly. You can see an example here:

https://www.lettuce.co.jp/products/detail/12184

Answer (score 7):

In informal Japanese, sometimes 'giongo' (onomatopoeic words) are changed to give a slightly different effect. In your example, くるくる ([definition](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8B%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8B-486440)) has become くるん and としていて has become てしてて. You see it in other giongo words sometimes. For example, つるつる/つるん(と), ぷるぷる/ぷるん(と), etc. I think it is more common with words that have the る sound. I'm sure others can provide more examples.